# Finding the Simplex tableau information

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, scip, simplex, pyscipopt

I am trying to find the simplex tableau information by PySCIPopt wrapper. I called some methods to get the related information like `scip.getLPColsData()` and `scip.getLPRowsData()`. However, as the problem cannot throw any issue, it seems the function does not call into the SCIP.

Also to call methods in the solving process we still need to make their appropriate callbacks and I am not aware of which one of the callbacks should be implied. Please, see the modifiable MRE [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JPQ22FutTZoDo9_JwWTmCAAM773_iOa1?usp=sharing).

Now, my questions are:

1. What is `scip.getVars(transformed = True)` meaning? and how can I
   get/make the transformed model?
2. Is it necessary to call some methods like `SCIP_RESULT.DIDNOTRUN` as
   it seems to be a flag?
3. Is there any illustrative example of how one can invoke such
   information from the solver?

Comment: Dear @Leon, may I have your insight about this?